# I wanted to make an image disappear with JavaScript but it's still the same why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a code that passes from image to image with javascript but I wanted when the data-slide-to was equal to 1 the image would disappear, but instead the image remains the same as if nothing happened, why isn't it working?

```
<section class="slider_section ">
            <div class="slider_bg_box">
               <img id="myImage" src="{{url ('assets/images/slider-bg.jpg')}}" alt="">
            </div>

            <script> 
               if($("li").attr("data-slide-to") == "1")
               {
                  document.getElementById("myImage").style.display = "none";
               }
            </script>

            <div class="container">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                     <li data-target="#customCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                     <li data-target="#customCarousel1" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                     <li data-target="#customCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
            </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement only runs once. You'll need some kind of listener to run it again when `data-slide-to` changes.

Comment: Also inline JavaScript as you have it is not recommended. It should always be in its own file. If you must have a `<script>` tag in your HTML, it should go at the bottom of the page as the last item.

Comment: @DM how should i do it then? I'm still kinda new to programming

Comment: @GuyPeace I am working on an answer for you to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the bootstrap4 documentation, it looks like you have some structure issues with your code. I would recommend reviewing the documentation first so that the format is correct before trying to use JavaScript to add functionality. Below is an example that is pertinent to your question.

Secondly, you should keep JavaScript and CSS in their own files.

*Note: Example pulled from www.w3schools.com.*

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```